# Api gateway for Microservices with Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, architecture

#### Inputs

For example, we have a few services.

1. Account service
2. Product service
3. Payment service

Each service is a separate Google Cloud Function. 
Each service has its own HTTP API. For example, the account service has:

1. https://REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/account/sign-up
2. https://REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/account/sign-in
3. https://REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/account/reset-password
4. etc

Each service has its own swagger documentation endpoint `/docs`.

#### Question

How can I make my Cloud Functions private (without public access) and place them behind some API Gateway?

#### Notes

Google offers Endpoints for Cloud Functions (see https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions ).
But, as I understand it, Endpoints allow you to define only the yaml OpenAPI file.

In this yaml file, I can define something like this:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Cloud Endpoints + GCF
  description: Sample API on Cloud Endpoints with a Google Cloud Functions backend
  version: 1.0.0
host: HOST
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /hello:
    get:
      summary: Greet a user
      operationId: hello
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/helloGET
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
```

But in my case, I need to have ability to proxy my cloud functions (like reverse proxy).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/architecture-overview).

[Extensible Service Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/specify-proxy-startup-options) is one of Endpoints components and is exactly what is needed in your case.

> The Extensible Service Proxy (ESP) is a high-performance, scalable
>   proxy that runs in front of an OpenAPI or gRPC API backend and
>   provides API management features such as authentication, monitoring,
>   and logging.

You might also find this link useful: [Configuring and Deploying an API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/configure-endpoints)